# Mutual recursion and JSLint - function was used before it was defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, jslint, mutual-recursion

If I write the following code, JSLint complains that **'isOdd' was used before it was defined**. Is there a way to write mutually recursive code and still please JSLint?

```
var isEven = function(n) {
    if (n === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return isOdd(n - 1);
};

var isOdd = function(n) {
    if (n === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return isEven(n - 1);
};
```

Comment: `function isOdd(n) ...etc..`

Comment: @JaromandaX JSLint still complains even if I use that format

Comment: it's to do with `no-use-before-define` option I guess

Comment: `var isOdd;` before `var isEven = ...` then remove `var` from your `var isOdd`

Comment: You should remove JSLint from your computer, stab it in the heart, break it into little pieces, burn those pieces, and then bury them. It was never a good tool, and now it's obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting these functions to methods of an object quell the error message from JSLint. This also does a better job of keeping the global namespace less polluted.

```
var numUtil = {
    isEven: function(n) {
        if (n === 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return this.isOdd(n - 1);
    },
    isOdd: function(n) {
        if (n === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.isEven(n - 1);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

For JSLint, you have to add a global variables directive to the top of the file, so that it ignores usage of temporary "undefined" functions and variables.

```js
/*global isOdd */

var isEven = function(n) {
    if (n === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return isOdd(n - 1);
};

var isOdd = function(n) {
    if (n === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return isEven(n - 1);
};
```

You could also declare `isOdd` at the top, but then you would change your actual code because a linting program doesn't understand hoisting:

```js
var isOdd;

var isEven = function(n) {
    if (n === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return isOdd(n - 1);
};

isOdd = function(n) {
    if (n === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return isEven(n - 1);
};
```

---