# Handling @typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define in mutual recursion

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

Let's say we have two functions that call each other:

```js
const a = () => {
  console.log("a");

  if (Math.random() > 0.9) {
    // Dodging infinite recursion.
    return;
  }

  b(); // 'b' was used before it was defined. (@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define) eslint
};

const b = () => {
  console.log("b");

  a();
};
```

First approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45808207/6212530) (`/* global b */` at top of file) doesn't work for me, while I don't think declaring variable before initialization is possible with `const`.

So what is the best way to handle this linting error?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you declare the variables before assigning the functions you'd be fine. Something like this:

```
let a: () => void, b: () => void;
a = () => {...}
b = () => {...}
```

Not sure it is better than just ignoring the rule for the mentioned line or just disabling the rule entirely.

Comment: I would personally just use an `eslint-disable` comment to ignore the warning and add a comment mentioning that the functions use mutual recursion, eg `// eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define -- the functions use mutual recursion and thus cannot be ordered to satisfy this rule`